# How does Tableau connect to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api, extended-events

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how various third party applications reach into a Microsoft SQL Server data warehouse and gather data before allowing report writers to work with it. I'm working with a SQL 2008 R2 instance and ultimately I want to capture all requests going into and out of the warehouse at a SQL level over a short period of time.

So right now I'm using Extended Events to do this, and the events I'm monitoring are:

```
SQL_STATEMENT_COMPLETED
SQL_STATEMENT_STARTING
SP_STATEMENT_COMPLETED
SP_STATEMENT_STARTING
RPC_STARTING
RPC_COMPLETED
```

However when I run this, open Tableau 8 and connect to the server and pull in data from a specific table, I don't see any activity in the XE. So am I missing an event that would see the SQL?

Comment: So do you see activity getting pulled back when you use SSMS or something instead of tableau?

Comment: Yes. I can see the queries being run by SSMS/Excel just fine, as well as some db health stuff that runs periodically. Just nothing from Tableau.

Comment: Ok, next dumb question: are you absolutely sure tableau is hitting the same instance? Can you show your connection strings?

Comment: Yeah, I'm positive that it's the right connection string, and my XE are too. I actually think I just figured it out by firing off Profiler with some additional events selected: It looks like Tableau triggers SQL:StmtStarting, SQL:BatchStarting, SP:StmtStarting rather than the events I was looking at.

Comment: I'm going to do a little more research on this and then will add my own answer once I get things showing up in XE.

Comment: Tableau uses cache pretty extensively. On workbook startup, it will do a query and hold the data in memory for quite a while. Part of what makes it fast. If you can, restart the service and see what happens in the eventing on the server.

Comment: Between my tests I've been completely closing out of the Tableau desktop program - I didn't see a service running that looked like it was attached to Tableau. However, now that I know what it's looking to do in SQL via Profiler (why didn't I just do that at the beginning) I think I've got a good idea of how to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

You can scrape the Tableau log files. It pretty much logs all the queries it executes and has some timestamp info too.

Comment: Your answer would be even more complete if you can direct people to where the log files are kept.